# File Upload S3 and heroku python

Tags: python, heroku, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a file to S3 using the s3.Object() method by creating a file in /tmp/ directory. I deployed it on heroku and its throwing an application error saying Worker timed out.

Below is my source code:

```
def writeAckFile(dt,num1,num2):

    dt = dt.split('/')
    dt = dt[2] + dt[0] + dt[1]

    final_content = str('D|' +num1+ '|' + num2 + '|' + dt + '\n')

    op_file = open('/tmp/Ack.txt', 'w')
    if op_file.mode == 'w':
        op_file.write(final_content)
    op_file.close()
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.Object('S3_BUCKET', 'Ack1.txt').put(Body=open('/tmp/Ack.txt', 'rb'))
```

Is there a easier way to achieve the same? using tempfiles?

Comment: Have you looked into uploading directly to S3 instead?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if that ack.txt is been created or not.

If its created you can use client instead of resource.

`client_s3 = boto3.client('s3')
client_s3.upload_file('/tmp/Ack.txt', bucket_name, 'Ack1.txt')`